# Display WordPress plugin after the header

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress. My plugin contains a form. I would like to display this form in certain pages after the header, but I'm unable to achieve this.

This is how I displayed the form until now. It shows the form on every site at the top, which is not what I want.

```
function pre_display_form() {
     include("form.php");
}
add_action("init", "pre_display_form");
```

I was experimenting with `add_action` and `add_filter`, but unsuccessfully. I'm not able to find the right hook.

I know there must be a way to do it. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: there is no hook for this. You could try js but the problem is themes can use whatever html mark up they want. Maybe try this hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form

Answer (score 1):

Try following, it should work for you:-

```
add_action('wp_head','wdm_form_include');
function wdm_form_include(  ) {
        //here you can assign page ids where you want to display form
        $page_ids = array(1,2,3);
        if(in_array(get_the_ID(),$page_ids)){
           //if current page id is in page ids array then including form
            include("form.php");
        }

}
```